# TRE fuzzy-regex library runtime-error in debug build: MSVCP90.dll is missing

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2008, dependencies, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to compile TRE under VS2008. It start in Release build fine, but in Debug it gives me the error `MSVCP90.dll is missing`:

[image]

I checked with Dependency Walker, they use only one function from it - `wctype()`. I tried copying MSVCP90.dll from "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcp90.dll", but that didn't work either, it gave me a runtime error `R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly`, so I abandoned that path.

What's suspicious is that they link to `msvcp90.dll` in Debug, instead of `msvcp90d.dll`. So I checked the Linker settings, and they link to `msvcprt.lib`. I tried replacing it with `msvcprtd.lib`, but it still tries to link to `msvcp90d.dll`.

I also tried rerunning vcredist_x86.exe and repairing my the VS2008 redistributables, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason - I needed to change the .lib file at the tre project as well.

So I needed to go to Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, and change it from `msvcprt.lib` to `msvcprtd.lib`, for both the `tre` and `retest` projects:

[image]

I'm posting this in case anyone else encounters the same problem.